# Nested Angular ui routers throw exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got this error when clicking on `ui-sref="favorite-list"`:

> Could not resolve 'favorite-list' from state 'studies'

I have code like this:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('study', {
            url: '/study/:studyId',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/study/study-edit.template.html',
            controller: 'StudyController'
        })
        .state('studyObject', {
            url: '/study/:studyId/studyObject/:studyObjectId',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/study-object/study-object-edit.template.html',
            controller: 'StudyObjectController'
        })
        .state('studies', {
            url: '/studies?all&field&term&page&sort&sort_dir',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/studies/studies.template.html',
            controller: 'StudiesController',
            onExit: function exitStudies(filterQuery) {
                filterQuery.emptyQuery();
            },
            menuElement: 'studies',
            resolve: {
                attributes: function (attribute, manageAttributes) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        })
        .state({
            name: 'studies.favorite-list',
            template: '<favorites-list></favorites-list>',
            parent: 'studies'
        });
```

and html:

```
<div class="left-menu" ng-class="{collapsed: menu.isCollapsed}" click-outside="closeMenu()">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <button role="button" ui-sref="favorite-list" ng-class="{'text-bold': favorites.active}">
                <img src="images/divos/star.svg" alt="Favorites" height="20" width="30"> Favorites
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

I've try with parent and without, using `.state('studies.favorite-list', {})` also using `ui-sref="studies.favorite-list"` but I'm keep getting this error. I'm using version 0.2.18 from bower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I've only needed to add comma before the name:

```
ui-sref=".favorite-list"
```